# Can I use Minecraft redstone to teach digital circuits?

Tags: digital-logic, education

I'm sorry if this question is off-topic. If it is, I would be thankful to know at which StackExchange site I should ask this question.

Let me say first, I never played Minecraft myself. But I heard you have something in this game called 'Redstone', with which you can implement logic gates like AND & OR. I read you make this quite complex, making full adders and ALUs. To me, it seems like a fun way to teach (the basics of) digital circuits.

My question is, do they behave similar to real logic circuits, or at least of ideal version of real logic circuits? Are there any important difference in functionality I have to know? And are there other people that use this game for this purpose?

I'm really intereseted in the answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally I think you'd end up spending a long time teaching people how to play the game and then build the gates in the game (and then building circuits out of them) than you would actually spend teaching people how logic gates work. Knowing how to make a logic gate from blocks in Minecraft doesn't exactly translate into the real world.

Comment: This is probably off topic for EE.SE. I suggest you review the [extensive material](https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft%20redstone%20circuits) available on the internet concerning redstone. There is plenty of documentation on the non-ideal behavior of the circuits and how they are important to the designs.

Comment: Digital logic is simple to implement. The game emulation would have no problem being accurate. But there are much simpler edu-tertainment tools or games to do it in.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for your reaction. Could you give me an example of such a game?

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks for your reaction. I didn't realize you had to build the gates in the game. I thought you could just choose some gates and link them together.

Comment: @Kevin That is possible if you're willing to use a mod (see http://ftb.gamepedia.com/RedLogic). However I'd still agree with TomCarpenter's point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good way to get introduced to it but too time consuming for complex circuits. I helped my 10 year old brother build a 4 bit multiplier (it took us the whole afternoon), a BCD to 7 segment decoder and a 7 segment display. But then, building a block-ram for example was boring without copy-paste.

We then switched to Logisim to build more complex circuits because it is way faster, even if it less fun.

There are good things:

- Speed of signal propagation introduces difficulties, especially for clock signal
- Signal attenuation over length is a problem and requires `repeaters`
- Wire crossing is a challenge and usually requires to build higher structures to stack crossover
- If you only use redstone, the only gates you have are `or` and `not` and it is interesting to build registers from it
- You can play with a bunch of input: button, lever, pressure plate, door
- You can play with a bunch of output: light, sound, piston, explosives

And bad things:

- Time consuming (you have to build scaffolding for your circuit)
- Redstone do not behave like electricity: you can produce energy from anywhere, and there is no way of forcing a signal down (lacks the CMOS symmetry)
- There is no problem with too many fan-out (gates do not consume any energy)
- Wire placement is tricky, sometimes you have to redesign a gate because two wire connect each-other where they should not
- No copy-paste, no automatic wiring, no possibility of moving a circuit: if you build a circuit too close to an other you must rebuild it

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I understand Minecraft Redstone it's not a good representation of physical electric circuits.

I'm happy you mentioned Logism, it looks like a nice program for simulation and I'll definitely look into it. This program seems like a better tool indeed.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't recommend it. There are a lot of weird quirks to redstone logic in Minecraft, and it's constrained by the mechanics of the game. In particular:

- Redstone circuits must be constructed on the surface of a structure in 3D space, and the player must move around that space to work on their circuit. Building that structure will suck up a lot of time.
- Many common designs for redstone logic gates rely on idiosyncratic elements of the game (e.g, pistons, hoppers, and light transmission)  which do not translate to real logic.
- There is no way to "cut, copy or paste" constructions in Minecraft. Constructing large hierarchical circuits will involve a lot of repetitive work.
- There are limitations on the overall size of a circuit. Beyond a certain size, it will stop working.

If you want to introduce students to digital logic, consider using a program like [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/). It may not be quite as 'hip' as Minecraft, but it has the advantage of actually being designed for this use.

Comment: Note that point 2 used to not be the case, so you could use an older version of Minecraft to avoid that.

Comment: To the third point: you can use third-party map editors to get around this, but then there's yet another tool to use.

Comment: Point 3 is only partially valid because people who do extensive red stone contraptions use WorldEdit which lets you easily cut, copy, and paste

Comment: @Insane To a degree. But at that point, if you're having to do all your construction in another program, you might as well just use a program that's designed for building and simulating digital circuits instead of messing around with Minecraft at all.

Comment: @duskwuff Oh yeah even a half valid 1 of those points is a better reason why NOT to use MC, but mods to make red stone wiring easier exist